# Unable to disable apparmor in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apparmor, budgie

I tried to open a pdf in my external HD with Evince (pdf reader), but apparmor denied. Then I tried to find Evince's profile to add a link to it in /etc/apparmor.d/disable in order to disable the profile. I used the command
**aa-status**
to find the profile. It shows:
snap.evince.evince

The apparmor manual page explains that some in the profiles list generated by the former command, the slashes are replaced by dots, so I tried to find /snap/evince/evince; it does not exist.

Then I tried to set the evince profile to "complain", instead of "enforce", using this command:
**sudo aa-complain snap.evince.evince**

Result:
Can't find snap.evince.evince in the system path list. If the name of the application is correct, please run 'which snap.evince.evince' as a user with correct PATH environment set up in order to find the fully-qualified path and use the full path as parameter.

I tried do use which and whereis to find the profile, but it was of no avail.

Then I used these commands:
**sudo systemctl stop apparmor

sudo systemctl disable apparmor**

I tried to open a pdf file with Evince, but AppArmor denied it. I rebooted and I am in the same situation.

Can I disable all profiles at once?
Can I disable a specific profile by any other mean?

P.S - I am asking this question because removing apparmor makes snap unusable, which is very counterproductive.
Thanks in advance.
I am using Ubuntu Budgie 20.04. LTS

Comment: did you try to disable apparmor via the kernel command line in grub? use `apparmor=0` in `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot hangs indefinitely on a start job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177328/boot-hangs-indefinitely-on-a-start-job)

Comment: I read quite a lot about apparmor and found that for the moment best choice for me is not disabling the complete service, but to put a profile in complain mode, meaning that this profile will not affect anymore the operation in question, but will just log it. In my case it was mysqld, so I ran `sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld`. Initially command was not working, so I found that I need to install apparmor utils with `sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils`.

Answer (score 5):

You can execute command `sudo aa-teardown`.
Here works like a charm.

Comment: what is the drawback of disabling this?

Comment: All your services will be opened and another disk areas can be reached. This can be a serious security hazard.

Comment: And what is the command to enable AppArmor again after using aa-teardown?

Comment: apparmor is so bad, there really is no security risk, by the way - it is not like Selinux

Comment: `aa-teardown` **can cause issues** if your application uses hats (change_hat). With the AppArmor profile unloaded, the application will be attempting to use a non-existent hat, which will be denied by AppArmor. I've been bitten by this in PHP-FPM.